# javascript event handling

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a very lightweight system to test a javascript framework I am building for work.

I've created a test function that acts as a wrapper invoking the function i am testing within a try/catch to report feedback without breaking my test cycle. The problem is that my catch isn't getting called when I deliberately create an error.

My code....

```
    /// <summary>
    ///     Acts as a wrapper to allow us to perform and report the result 
    ///     of each individual
    ///     test without blocking further tests.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="selector" type="String">
    ///     The id jQuery selector e.g #versionTests to repot feedback to.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="testFunction" type="Function">
    ///     The test function to call.
    /// </param>
    test: function (selector, testFunction) {

        try {
            // now we are calling our own callback function
            if (typeof testFunction === 'function') {

                testFunction.call();
            }
        } catch (e) {

       jQuery(selector).addClass("error").append("<p>" + e.description + "</p>");

        }

    }
```

Thanks in advance....

EDIT.. Added called code for clarity.

The test function that I am calling is basically on that calls this....

```
    testEqualizeHeight: function () {

        PeachUI("div.heightTest").equalizeHeight();
    }
```

Which calls this....... (`this.selector` is a property that reflect jQuerys selector.)
note the missing `'$'` on `$selector.height(tallest);`

```
equalizeHeight: function () {
    /// <summary>
    ///     Equalizes the height of the specified element(s).
    /// </summary>

    var $tallest = 0, $selector = this.selector;

    $selector.each(function () {

        var $height = jQuery(this).height();

        if ($height > $tallest) {

            $tallest = $height;
        }
    });

    // ie6 height is the same as min-height for other browsers.
    if (PeachUI.browser.ie6) {

        $selector.height(tallest);

    } else {

        $selector.css("min-height", $tallest);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code that is supposed to create the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When looking in your [source code](http://jsfiddle.net/jamessouth/yCTjm/) it appeared to me that you do this remarkable thing (last lines):

```
PeachTest.test("#versionTests", PeachTest.testVersion());
PeachTest.test("#browserTests", PeachTest.testBrowser());
PeachTest.test("#isNumericTests", PeachTest.testNumeric);
PeachTest.test("#heightTests", PeachTest.testEqualizeHeight());
```

Here you pass a reference to `PeachTest.testNumeric` to `PeachTest.test`, but you're calling the other three test functions and pass the values those functions return to `PeachTest.test`.

Remove the function call operators (`()`) behind those parameters and your test function works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

You actually don't need to invoke `.call()`. You can just use:

```
testFunction();
```

if you want to setup the execution context explicitly, you can use `.call(context, param1, param2, ..)`

How do you "deliberately" create an error? Try to throw an exception within `testFunction` like

```
throw new Error('Foo Bar');
```

Last thing to mention here is, that the `exception object` does not own the property `description` but `message`.

Example: http://www.jsfiddle.net/RUeEm/

Comment: @ jAndy: You can blame w3schools for the description property. http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_try_catch.asp I didn't realise it was an MS only thing.

Comment: @James: W3Schools is **full** of mistakes, bad coding practices, horrible examples, etc. And be aware that W3Schools is not at all affiliated to the W3C. For a better guide, see [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error#Properties_2) (and you can read there that `description` is a proprietary property).

Comment: @JamesSouth: I don't blame anybody. I just wanted to point that out :)

Comment: @jAndy Sorry for the slow reply (long weekend.) I've tried what you have suggested but the error message just does not get passed through to the handler. It's beyond my skills atm to figure it out. I've created an example on fiddle if you fancy a crack http://jsfiddle.net/jamessouth/yCTjm/

Comment: @James: Why on earth do you use that kind of browser sniffing in your jsfiddle (using feature inference of the jQuery library)? jQuery itself already does [browser sniffing out of the box](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.browser/) and moreover, it's hardly ever needed anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Either testFunction is not getting called (it is wrapped in a conditional), or your code to add the error is incorrect.

I would use a debugger to trace the test execution and verify that it is following the path you think it is.  Or console.logs()

Comment: @ hvgotcodes: testfunction is definitely getting called as it runs when i remove the error.